# Is space of sequence total bounded under 1-norm?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let S be the set of all sequences $x = \{x_n\}$ of real numbers such  that only a finite number of the $x_n$ are $\ne 0$. Define $d(x,y) = max |x_n - y_n|$.  Is the space complete? Show that the $\delta$-neighborhoods are not totally  bounded.

It’s from *Complex Analysis* of *Lars V. Ahlfors*.

I think I can prove it to be complete by showing that every Cauchy sequence converges. But why is it not totally bounded? I have a thought but I don’t know how to write it down. The $d(x,y)$ is a real number so I think the$\delta$-neighborhood should be exactly like a disc in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, thus we can not measure its volume and do the same estimate like it’s in the finite dimension space. But how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is not complete. The sequence$$\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots,\frac1n,0,0,\ldots\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$$is a Cauchy sequence wich doesn't converge.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. It’s not complete. And how can I prove it not to be total bounded? Thank you.

Comment: @HanceWu Consider the closed ball centered at the null sequence with radius $1$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, let $e(n)$ be the sequence such that$$e(n)_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }k=n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then$$n\neq m\implies d\bigl(e(n),e(m)\bigr)=1$$and therefore you cannot cover it with balls whose radius is smaller than $1$. The same argument applies to any $\delta$-neighborhood of any point.

Comment: I find the sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{n},0,0)$ converges to $(1,\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{n},...)$. And my proof of completeness is: $\forall \ n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the $n$th elements converges, so the sequence have a limit consisting of all limits of the elements.

Comment: @HanceWu The sequence $\left(1,\frac12,\frac,13,\ldots\right)$ doesn't belong to your space.

Comment: Ah, that’s the point! Thanks a lot!!!!